# NUnit throws System.InvalidOperationException: "All test threads are blocked."

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, nunit

Today I went to run my NUnit tests, and found suddenly that a ton were failing! The cause of nearly all failures was the same:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation.   ---->
>   System.InvalidOperationException : All test threads are blocked. Did
>   you start new threads that the test doesn't know about?

When I Googled this exception, I found no reference of it in relation to NUnit. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Well, did you start any threads? Any Task.Wait() ?

Comment: What happens when you run a single test?

Comment: I modified the codebase to throw a new kind of exception, but many of the tests that are failing do not have anything to do with the new exception-throwing code.

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the exception and inner exception. please post it too.

Comment: Running a single test has identical results. There are lots of threads in the code, and none of it I wrote myself. I'll do some poking at the code and report back if I fix it or need any more help.

Comment: Which version of NUnit and which version of the NUnit VS Adapter ?

Comment: NUnit 2.6.4. The latest NUnit V2 VS Adapter, straight from the extension manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

I had made a change which resulted in a whole lot of tests stuck waiting forever for something which never happened. This manifested itself in some tests as hanging forever, and in the remainder as raising the aforementioned `InvalidOperationException`.

So, in brief, when a lot of your tests hang forever and NUnit tries to parallelize testing, it runs out of threads and complains.

I originally posted this question not because my tests were failing, but because there were no resources out there when I Googled the mysterious exception. Hopefully this answer can help someone else who is mystified by this error in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Hope I can comment below, but anyways, which NUnit adapter are you using?

Found an [issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/14) reported with NUnit adapter 3.0.0.0

[image]

Comment: 2.6.4. We're a little behind the times. That issue report does look surprisingly familiar though.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be relevant. `TargetInvocationException` is the wrapper exception which will be thrown when dealing with reflection. Nunit obviously uses reflection and that's why `TargetInvocationException`; apart from that nothing seems relevant for me. We really need to check at inner exception when you get the TargetInvocationException